# How to compare object in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I'm currently doing a checking for item in cart. The item can  be redeemed multiple time but is limited to certain number. Each item has an attribute redeem_count which store the number of time that it can be redeemed. So, below is my coding for checking the total number of each item redeemed.

```
var previousCoupon = "";
var currentCoupon = "";
int count = 0;
foreach (var p in cart.Promotions)
{
    var query = db.wmp_mst_mcp_promo
               .Where(a => a.wmp_mcp_promo_id == p.PromotionId)
               .Where(a => a.wmp_redeem_count != null && a.wmp_redeem_count > 0)
               .SingleOrDefault();

    if (query != null)
    {
        currentCoupon = query.wmp_mcp_promo_id;

        if (previousCoupon == currentCoupon)
            count++;
        else
            count = 0;

        previousCoupon = currentCoupon;

        if (count > query.wmp_redeem_count)
            result.Invalidate(string.Format("You are not allowed to redeem more than {0} \"{1}\" voucher in 1 order", query.wmp_redeem_count, query.wmp_descriptions));
```

As you can see, the coding works but only if the same item are redeemed in order. This might not valid because not all customer will redeem the item in order. Bug will occur if they redeem for example item A, then item B, and then item A again. It will work only if item A, item A then item B.

**Edited**

I want to store any item that have same ID and get only one of it attribute redeem_count so that I can do if statement on it. The redeem_count is different for each item.

**Example**

Item in cart

- item A - 2 (redeem_count=2) **Valid**
- item B - 2 (redeem_count=1) **Invalid**
- item C - 3 (redeem_count=4) **Valid**

So it will throw the result.Invalidate

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: @wkl sorry. i mistyped it.

Comment: I would iterate all Promotions, check if the Id is inside a HashSet. If it is increase redeem_count, if it isnt add that Id to HashSet. Would that be what you want?

Comment: @Mats391 Hi. Actually I want to compare the ID of each item and if it same with other item, the count for the item will increase. But only the count for that item increase. Example, if item A occur twice, so the count for item A become 2 while if item B is 3, the count for item B become 3 too.

Comment: Still do not quite get when to increase what count, but I do think the better solution is to remember the objects you already looked at and check if your item is already in those. I would have done it similar to wkl answer

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like (pseudocode):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string /*item_Id*/, int /*count*/>;
// count redemptions for each id
foreach(var item in cart)
{
    if(dict.ContainsKey(item.Id))
         dict[item.Id]++;
    else
        dict.Add(item.Id, 1);
}

// check if any of them violate the allowed maximum
foreach( var itemId in dict.Keys)
{
    if(dict[itemId ] > GetMaxRedeemCount(itemId))
    {
        result.Invalidate(...);
        // you may want to break here...
        // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could already compare `count` to redeem count in the first loop after adding. Would get rid of second loop

Comment: @Mats391 Yes, this would remove the second loop but it would perform even more comparisons and calls to `GetMaxRedeemCount`(one per item instead of one per item_id). So I do not see an advantage w.r.t. performance. Concerning readability, personally, I would prefer two loops (and maybe even convert each of them to a separate method).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution;

```
 var previousCoupon = "";
        var currentCoupon = "";
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var p in cart.Promotions)
        {
            var query = db.wmp_mst_mcp_promo
                .Where(a => a.wmp_mcp_promo_id == p.PromotionId)
                .Where(a => a.wmp_redeem_count != null && a.wmp_redeem_count > 0);
if (query != null)
{
       foreach(var queryItems in query)
              {
                currentCoupon = query.wmp_mcp_promo_id;

                if (previousCoupon == currentCoupon)
                    count++;
                else
                    count = 0;

                previousCoupon = currentCoupon;
            }
}
                if (count > query.wmp_redeem_count)
                    result.Invalidate(string.Format("You are not allowed to redeem more than {0} \"{1}\" voucher in 1 order", query.wmp_redeem_count, query.wmp_descriptions));
```

Comment: i saw ur edit now.  Can u try debug and can u tell me what is results ur linq code, is that giving u any value invalid? because i think this code always give valid jus one result

Comment: Yes, there would be only one result like you stated. I want it to check each of the item if any of it are redeemed more than it's redeem_count. I used foreach loop for that but it only work like I mention on the question above where the same item need to be next to each other.